# mongodb shutdown option unavailable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

My current problem: I have a production server and just updated mongod but lost some functionality.

In earlier versions (`v2.0.6`) I was able to run `mongod` with the `--shutdown` option and it would kill all other instances.

Now with version `v2.4.5` - if I run:

```
mongod --shutdown
```

The result is:

```
error command line: unknown option shutdown
use --help for help
```

Version info: `mongod --version`

```
db version v2.4.5
Mon Sep 16 14:09:38.994 git version: a2ddc68ba7c9cee17bfe69ed840383ec3506602b
```

It's important that I have this option or something similar to it because I have a server process that manages the new instance.

For example:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
result    = spawn('mongod', ['--quiet', '--shutdown', '--directoryperdb', '--dbpath', __dirname + '/database']);
```

Edit:
The Mongodb documentation still has `--shutdown` command option.
Link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/

```
Alternately, you can shut down the mongod instance:

using the --shutdown option
from a driver using the shutdown. For details, see the drivers documentation for your driver.
```

Edit:

**I felt I should update this question. This issue has been fixed in the mongojs wrapper as of v0.9.6. However, there are still some kinks to be worked out as listed in issue [#97](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs/issues/97) but should work for most requirements.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using db.shutdownServer() in the mongo shell?

From the documentation:

> To stop a mongod instance running in the background or foreground,
>   issue the db.shutdownServer() helper in the mongo shell. Use the
>   following sequence:
>
> To open the mongo shell for a mongod instance running on the default
>   port of 27017, issue the following command:
>
> ```
> mongo
> ```
>
> To switch to the admin database and shutdown the mongod instance,
>   issue the following commands:
>
> ```
> use admin
> db.shutdownServer()
> ```
>
> You may only use db.shutdownServer() when connected to the mongod when
>   authenticated to the admin database or on systems without
>   authentication connected via the localhost interface.

---

Per your comments, you can do the same thing by running the [shutdown command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/shutdown/) *against the admin database* in a driver:

```
{shutdown : 1}
```

I'm not the most familiar with the node.js driver, but you have two options for running commands in drivers in general, and one should always work:

1. Use your driver's wrapper for runCommand (which you can use in the mongo shell like so:)

   db.runCommand({shutdown : 1});
2. Use the built-in `$cmd` pseudo-collection to run your commands.  Wrappers for commands actually use this method, and if you have no other options, you can run queries against $cmd to shutdown a server:

   db.$cmd.findOne({"shutdown":1})

If you aren't running a driver, you can use the [REST interface](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/) if you have it exposed (use the `--rest` command-line option when running `mongod`).  By making a POST request, you can run commands against the admin database:

```
http://localhost:28017/admin/$cmd/?filter_shutdown=1&limit=1
```

which is the equivalent of running the previous query against `$cmd`.

Comment: No, I have not tried that. That would force me to write more code to handle that situation though, whereas the command line option was easy and built-in.

Comment: Oh!  I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question.  I'll go ahead and edit my answer.

Comment: That helps quite a bit! When I use the command from mongo shell everything works flawlessly but I suppose I should of stated that I am using mongojs. In which, the command does not work. Looks like I will be making a ticket on the mongojs Github.

Comment: I felt I should update this answer. This issue has been fixed in the mongojs wrapper as of v0.9.6. There are still some kinks to be worked out as listed in issue #97 but should work for most requirements.

Answer (score 11):

Since the "--shutdown" option is not available in newer versions of mongo, you now have to kill the process manually or login and run:

```
use admin;
db.shutdownServer();
```

However you can accomplish this in one line by doing:

```
mongo 127.0.0.1/admin --eval "db.shutdownServer()"
```

Assuming that you're connecting to your local db at 127.0.0.1.  You can only run 1 line using the --eval param, so doing `use admin; db.shutdownServer();` is not an option, however you can accomplish connecting to the admin db by adding that "/admin" after the IP.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else found this command through [the tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/) while running OS X, this command is only available on Linux machines and is not available on OS X (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--shutdown where it states this explicitly). I'm not sure if that's what was happening with the original poster but hope it helps someone.